# How can I see a list of new packages for my system

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa

I run muon every few days to keep my system up to date. In the lower left corner, there is a number of available packages which keeps getting bigger! It makes me curious to see what they are.

I would like a way to list these new packages (with short descriptions) to see if any of them interest me (perhaps, newer than some date I would specify).

Just to be clear, I am interested in seeing "new" packages - not updates to current ones - which muon already does - at least for the ones I have installed.

Since my sources lists include a number of repos and ppas, I'd like something that takes this into account.

I like guis, but am also comfortable with using utilities like apt-get from the command line.

I am currently running kubuntu precise with a lot of backports including KDE 4.12.2 on my notebook.